# Visual Studio 2017 Express で「形式を指定して貼り付け」を出す方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio

お世話になります。
XML→クラスへの自動変換を行いたくて、「形式を指定して貼り付け」を出す方法を探しております。
色々調べた結果、Visual Studio 2017では「ASP.NETとWeb開発」を追加することで使用可能になるようですが、「Express」ではインストール時やVisual Studio Installerの「変更」ボタンでは「ASP.NETとWeb開発」のインストール項目が出てこず手詰まりとなりました。

ここからご質問の本題ですが、タイトルにあるように、
Visual Studio 2017 Express で「形式を指定して貼り付け」を出す方法
または、Visual Studio 2017 Express で「ASP.NETとWeb開発」をインストールする方法はありますでしょうか？

以上、申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「形式を選択して貼り付け」を表示するのが目的なのでしょうか？
記事対象はJSONですが、おそらくここを参照してのことだと思います。
[Visual Studio 2017 × 形式を選択して貼り付け × 「編集」メニューに表示されない問題に対応してみた](https://www.kinakomotitti.net/entry/2018/04/16/231941)

> 形式を選択して貼り付け機能をメニューに表示するためには、「ASP.NETとWeb開発」機能が必要です。

[VisualStudio コピペ JSONをClassとして貼り付けられるtips](https://qiita.com/tsgkdt/items/3e108b2b6c7f2a7e0b21)

> 試した環境は、VisualStudio2015 CommunityEditionです。
>   [編集]-[形式を選択して貼り付け(s)]　から[Paste JSON As Classes]を選択します。

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express)によると、
Visual Studio Express 2017 は for Windows Desktopしかなく、「ASP.NETとWeb開発」をインストールするのは無理そうです。
Wikipediaにあるように、Visual Studio Express 2015 for WebかVisual Studio Community 2017(最新は2019)を使えば良いのでは？

---

しかし、本当の目的は「XML→クラスへの自動変換」が出来るようにすることではないですか？
自動変換は出来なくても、色々とツールはあるようなので、それらで代替を考えてみても良いのではないでしょうか。

`xsd.exe`というプログラムがあれば、何とかなるでしょう、という記事。
[Auto generating Entity classes with xsd.exe for XML Serialization and De-Serialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yojoshi/2011/05/14/auto-generating-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe-for-xml-serialization-and-de-serialization/)
[Creating XSD of a XML Using Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/creating-xsd-of-a-xml-using-visual-studio/)

フル機能のVisualStudioだと[Visual Studio の XML ツール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/xml-tools/xml-tools-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)というのがあるそうなので、Visual Studio Expressにそれがあれば同等のことが出来るかも。
非常に古いですがこんな記事も。
[.NETで簡単XML 第7回 VS.NETでXML Schemaを活用する（作成編）](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/easyxml/easyxml07/easyxml07_02.html)

上記を含めて.NETのAPIを駆使すれば、色々出来そうな環境は既に揃っているのかもしれません。
[XML ドキュメントと XML データ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/data/xml/)

> .NET Framework には、XML 対応アプリを容易に構築するための、包括的で統合された一連のクラスが用意されています。 次の名前空間のクラスでは、XML の解析と書き込み、メモリ内での XML データの編集、データの検証、および XSLT 変換がサポートされます。

独立した外部ツールもいくつかあるようなので、それを使うとか。
[Convert XML to C# Object](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1163664/Convert-XML-to-Csharp-Object)
[From XML to Strong Types in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11317/From-XML-to-Strong-Types-in-C)
[Xml2CSharp.com](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

---

なお、nugetリポジトリに[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/) / [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/)というのがあって、nugetがVisual Studio Expressで使えるか、使えたとしてそれらのパッケージがインストール出来るか、インストール出来ても「形式を選択して貼り付け」が表示されるか、といったことはまったく不明ですが、一応情報として。